# how to display multiple views in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native
I have created a view call container and I have styled it now when I create another view inside the container view I get some errors running my code on the browser. my emulator takes a lot of time to load
below is the code to my app.js file

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button,TextInput } from 'react-native';
export default function App() {
 return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
    <view style={styles.header}>
     <text>Hello Header</text>
     <text>Hello Header</text>
    </view>
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
</View>
);
}
```

here is the style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    
  },
  header:{
     backgroundColor:'green',
     padding:23,
  },
  input:{
    padding:5,
    paddingLeft:15,
    paddingRight:15,
    marginTop:5,
    marginBottom:5, 
    backgroundColor:'#f8f8f8',
    height:50,
    width:330,
    paddingHorizontal:0,
    borderWidth:2,
    borderColor:'#fff',
    borderRadius:10
  },
  login:{
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    paddingHorizontal:0,
    width:320,
    paddingRight:15,
  }
});
```

and here is the error from the browser

```
Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.
    in view (at App.js:9)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (at App.js:8)
    in App (created by ExpoRootComponent)
    in ExpoRootComponent
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in div (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

Comment: This is just a syntax error. Uppercase to Lowercase issue. You should change "v" at view to "V". view to View. This question needs to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you to do is change the header view from view to View

Comment: @Manuel need to change from text to Text also.

Answer (score 1):

Change the inner view from **view** to **View**